# How to build two <table> tags using One loop inside index View

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I am building two conference lists, the right side div (8 col) suppose to contain all conferences, while the left side div (4 col) suppose to contain the featured conferences only. I have performed it using two loops and it will affect the performance. 
My question is how to loop through both divs using one foreach loop ?

```
<table class="table-hover table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventNameAr)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventNameEn)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Organizers)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Speciality)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventDate)
        </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventNameAr)</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventNameEn)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="ApplicationUsers" asp-route-id="@item.ApplicationUser.Id">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ApplicationUser.ArName)
                </a>
                <img class="img-rounded" src="@Url.Content("~/" + @ARID.Properties.Resources.ProfileImageFolder + "/" + item.ApplicationUser.ProfileImage)" width="50" height="50" /><br />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw(item.Organizers)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.ArCountryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Speciality.ArSpecialityName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
            </td>

            <td>
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admins") || item.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id)
                {
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>

                }
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admins"))
                {
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: *You can't*. Not in this space-time continuum, anyways. However, a for loop is hardly a performance concern in and of itself.

Comment: hello chris can you add your comment as answer ...i want to choose it as best answer to make other people benefit...